# How to create custom navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to create `custom navigation drawer` , but i have button and `EditText` in `navigation` . I use this to filter.but i cant create like this.

[image: like this]

Comment: whats the problem in creating it ? Navigation drawer is also a view and you can use any view subclass with it

Comment: i can use editText and button in menu>"my xml"

Comment: You can use normal layout xml in navigation drawer too. Its not mandatory to usemenu.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly easy to achieve customization

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!--here is your navigation drawer just create what layout you want inside it-->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <!--here you can create your custom view like this-->

          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

after that you can simply defined the ID same we do for other view and set `onclicklistener` on them to get click event